# Inconsistent CPU load on debian

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, debian, tomcat, central-processing-unit

This server runs Apache2, Tomcat6 and MySQL.(if that makes any difference you tell me :)

Using htop i can see the cpu load on each of the 4 cores.

What I do not understand is witch processes are using the actual cores.
It seems to me that only 2% should be used in total, can any one explain?

[image]

using sar I see an average CPU load of 15% I just cant figure out witch processes that are actually causing the load.

Comment: Did you run htop as root? Is this a bare metal machine, or a container? In some configurations, some processes are hidden to other users.

Comment: Please don't post information from a console window as a picture. Cut and paste (using the proper formatting) makes it a lot easier for everyone.

Comment: yes htop was run by root, im not sure what you mean by bare matel machine? its a virtual machine hosted by some company, im afraid i do not know what they use for virtualization. 
also did not know one cloud actually cupy from htop.